# Launch Chrome Apps from Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I'm running Google Chrome 33 (desktop mode, **not** immersive mode) on Windows 8.1 Professional. I just recently installed the TweetDeck app for Google Chrome. I'm not used to Google Chrome apps too much just yet, and I'm trying to find a way to launch Chrome apps from the Google Chrome Omnibox.

Is this possible? When I search for "TweetDeck" in the Omnibox, it does not list any Chrome apps in the results, only web results.

Being that I am a very heavy keyboard user, I would like to be able to launch Chrome apps from the Omnibox. If anyone can shed light on this methodology, I would appreciate it, so I can avoid using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I have simply "bookmarked" the `chrome-extension://........` URL, so I can search for it in the Omnibox. Not an elegant solution, since the app's icon doesn't show up next to the search, but it works at least.